# Proving a bounded monotone function has finite one-sided limits

Tags: real-analysis

all! I got stuck on this question today, although it seemed straight forward when I started. Here is the proposed problem:

Let *a* and *b* be extended real numbers with *a* $\lt$ *b*. Prove that if *f* is a bounded, monotone function on the interval (*a*, *b*), then $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)$ both exist and are finite.

I started by using the fact that *f* has a sup and inf, meaning that the limits must exist and be finite because *x* $\epsilon$ (*a*,*b*). I am just not sure how to prove this rigorously. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

The idea is that monotonicity implies the inf and sup must be the one-sided limits at the end points.

Suppose $f$ is monotonically increasing. Pick $\epsilon > 0$. Let $\sup_{x \in (a,b)}f(x) = M$. Since $M$ is a least upper bound, there exists some $c \in (a,b)$ such that $M - f(c) < \epsilon$. Let $\delta = b - c$. Then if $b - x < \delta$ for $x \in (a,b)$, we have $x > c$, hence $f(x) \geq f(c)$ by monotonicity. Therefore $M - f(x) \leq M - f(c) < \epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you. Can you summarize in words what you are trying to do please?

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality, suppose that $f$ is increasing.  Let $L = \sup\{f(x) : x \in (a,b)\} < \infty$.  We wish to show that $\lim_{x \to a^-}f(x) = L$.  That is, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta$ such that $a-\delta < x < a \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

To that end, let $\delta$ be such that $f(a - \delta) > L - \epsilon$, noting that such a $\delta$ must exist by the definition of a supremum.  Now, to fill in the blanks, show that this $\delta$ satisfies the above requirement.

Comment: Thank you. Why you used W.L.O.G here please?

Comment: @Avv If $f$ is decreasing, the same logic could be applied to $-f$, which is increasing, to reach the same conclusion.